# Strange polynomial analog of the Bell numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

Let $\vec{x} = (x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots)$ and $\vec{y}=(y_1,y_2,y_3, \dots)$ be two systems of parameters/variables. The *Motzkin*
polynomials $P_n(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ for $n \geq 0$ are defined by the following quadratic recursion

\begin{equation}
P_n(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \ = \ x_0 P_{n-1}(\vec{x},\vec{y})
\, + \, \sum_{i \, = \, 0}^{n-2} \, y_1P_i(\vec{x}_+, \vec{y}_+) P_{n-i-1}(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \end{equation}

where $P_0(\vec{x},\vec{y}) := 1$ and $P_1(\vec{x},\vec{y}) := x_0$ are the initial polynomials and where $\vec{x}_+:= (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ and $\vec{y}_+:=(y_2,y_3,y_4, \dots)$ are the respective one-step shifts of the sequences $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$. From an enumerative standpoint, the Motzkin polynomial $P_n(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ is the multi-variate generating function of all Motzkin paths with $n$ steps: Each horizontal step (at level $k$) is weighted $x_k$, each ascending step (at level $k$) is weighted $y_k$, and the overall weight of the path is the product of weights of all horizontal steps and ascents which are taken. I should add that the generating
function $\sum_{n \geq 0} P_n(\vec{x},\vec{y})z^n$ can be be formally expressed as the following Jacobi continued fraction involving the parameters $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$

\begin{equation}
J_{\vec{x}, \vec{y}} \, (z) \ := \
{1 \over {1 - x_0z - {\displaystyle y_1z^2 \over {\displaystyle 1 - x_1 z - {\displaystyle y_2z^2 \over 
{\displaystyle 1 - x_2 z - {\displaystyle y_3z^2 \over {\ddots } } } } } } } }
\end{equation}

I'm concerned with the following specialization. For integers $k \geq 1$ let $x_{k-1} = \sigma + k - 1$ and $y_k = \sigma + k -1$ where $\sigma$ is an indeterminate. Since $\sigma$ is the operative variable I shall, for brevity's sake, write $P_n(\sigma)$ instead of $P_n(\vec{x},\vec{y})$. Brute force calculations reveal that

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
P_0(\sigma) \, =1 \\
P_1(\sigma) \, = \sigma \\
P_2(\sigma) \, = \sigma^2 + \sigma\\
P_3(\sigma) \, = \sigma^3 + 3\sigma^2  + \sigma \\
P_4(\sigma) \, = \sigma^4 + 6\sigma^3 + 6\sigma^2 + 2\sigma \\
P_5(\sigma) \, = \sigma^5 + 10\sigma^4 + 20\sigma^3 + 16\sigma^2 + 5\sigma \\
P_6(\sigma) \, = \sigma^6 + 15\sigma^5 + 50\sigma^4 + 71\sigma^3 + 51\sigma^2 + 15\sigma \\
P_7(\sigma) \, = \sigma^7 + 21\sigma^6 + 105\sigma^5 + 231\sigma^4 + 281\sigma^3 + 186\sigma^2 + 52\sigma
\end{array} 
\end{equation}

Evidence *seems* to suggest that $P_n(1) = B_n$ where
$B_n$ is the $n$-th *Bell number* while $P_n(2)$ counts the number of *irreducible set partitions* of size $n$ (see sequence A074664 at the OEIS). Furthermore

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
\big[\sigma] \, P_n(\sigma)
&\displaystyle = \, B_{n-2} \ \text{for $n \geq 2$} \\
\big[\sigma^{n-2}\big] \, P_n(\sigma)
&\displaystyle = \, {1 \over {12}} \, n^2(n^2-1) \ \text{for $n \geq 3$} \\
\big[\sigma^{n-1}\big] \, P_n(\sigma)
&\displaystyle = \, \binom{n}{2} \ \text{for $n \geq 2$} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $[\sigma^k] \, P_n(\sigma)$ denotes the coefficient of $\sigma^k$
occurring in $P_n(\sigma)$.
For $0 \leq n \leq 3$ we have $P_n(\sigma) = T_n(\sigma)$ where $T_n(\sigma)$ is the *Touchard polynomial* but this coincidence ceases for $n \geq 4$.

**Question:** Are the $P_n(\sigma)$ polynomials known? Does the generating function $\sum_{n \geq 0} P_n(\sigma) z^n$ have a nice form?

thanks, jeanne.

**Up-date:** Rephrasing the calculation in Somos' post and also Following Qiaochu Yuan's suggestion
to use the continued fraction expansion of the generating function $J(\sigma, z):= \sum_{n \geq 0} P_n(\sigma) z^n$ we get
the *functional equation*

\begin{equation} 
J(\sigma, z) \ = \
{1 \over {1 - \sigma z - \sigma z^2 J(\sigma +1 ,\ z)  }}
\end{equation}

which we can re-write in terms of
linear fractional transformations
as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 - \sigma z & -1 \\ \sigma z^2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot J(\sigma, z)
&\displaystyle = \ {(1 - \sigma z)J(\sigma,z) \, - \, 1 \over{\sigma z^2 J(\sigma, z)}} \\ \\
&= \
J(\sigma +1 ,z)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The term "nice form" might entail having a differential-recursive formula for the polynomials $P_n(\sigma)$ analogous to the *Rodrigues formula* for the Touchard polynomials, namely:

\begin{equation}
T_{n+1}(x) \ = \ x \Big(1 \, + \, {d \over {dx}} \Big) T_n(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you have the generating function of this version of the Motzkin numbers off the top of your head?

Comment: Well, the Motzkin numbers themselves have generating function $\frac{1 - x - \sqrt{1 - 2x - 3x^2}}{2x^2}$ which is not so bad (and in particular elementary). I know a version of the Motzkin polynomials whose generating function is an elegant continued fraction (https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/moments-hankel-determinants-orthogonal-polynomials-motzkin-paths-and-continued-fractions/) but I'm not sure if the variables are the same as yours. If you wrote out the first few of your Motzkin polynomials I could try to check.

Comment: I should say that the generating function $\sum_{n \geq 0} P_n(\vec{x}, \vec{y})z^n$ can be formally expressed as a Jacobi continued fraction. But I'm not sure if this helps, because the Jacobi continued fractions is my starting point.

Comment: I think the Jacobi continued fraction helps; seems like you ought to be able to use it to write $P(\sigma, z) = \sum P_n(\sigma) z^n$ in terms of $P(\sigma+1, z)$ or something like that?

Comment: Given the appearance of Bell numbers, I wonder if it might be more fruitful to consider an exponential generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{P_n(\sigma)}{n!} z^n$?

Comment: You're right that the form of the exponential generating function is better, but one of the motivations of my question stems from a case of the Stieltjes moment problem --- in which case you want the ordinary (moment) generating function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the monic polynomials $\,P_n(x)\,$ of
degree $n$ in $x$ such that its ordinary generating
function $\, f_x(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)z^n \,$
satisfies the equation

$$ f_x(z) = \frac1{1 - xz - xz^2\,f_{x+1}(z)} =
 1 + (x)z + (x+x^2)z^2 + (x+3x^2+x^3)z^3 + \cdots.$$

This equation is equivalent to the recursion

$$ P_0(x) = 1,\quad P_{n+1}(x) = x\,P_n(x) + x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_k(x+1)P_{n-1-k}(x). $$

The answer to your first question

> Are the $\,P_n(σ)\,$ polynomials known?

is probably "no" but should be "yes". A lookup in the OEIS
did not find any match for the triangular sequence of
**coefficients** which is strong evidence that it is not
yet a known sequence but not conclusive. I created
[A357438](https://oeis.org/A357438)
for this sequence and so that may contribute to its reknown. However, Peter Luschny created in 2018
[A321960](https://oeis.org/A321960)
which is the array $\,\{P_n(k)\}_{n,k=0}^\infty\,$ read
by antidiagonals with a definition equivalent
to $\,f_x(z)$ and it links to
[A321964](https://oeis.org/A321964)
which states

> We say a sequence R is Jacobi generated by the sequences
> U and V if R are the coefficients of the series expansion
> of the Jacobi continued fraction, recursively defined by
> m = 1 - V(k)*x - U(k)*x^p/m, starting m = 1 and terminating
> with 1/m, k iterating downwards from a given length to 1.
> p is some integer (in the classic case p = 2).

In general, given a sequence of polynomials with integer
coefficients, the triangular sequence of coefficients may
be listed in the OEIS and/or the array of values of the
polynomials for nonnegative integers read by antidiagonals.
In this particular case, now **both** are in the OIES

My answer to your second question

> Does the generating function $\sum_{n \geq 0} P_n(\sigma)
>  z^n$ have a nice form?

is that this is hard to tell since "nice form" is not a well
defined term. I am still looking for something like that.

---

You may be interested in the closely related blog article by
Qiaochu Yuan ["Moments, Hankel determinants, orthogonal
polynomials, Motzkin paths, and continued fractions"](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/moments-hankel-determinants-orthogonal-polynomials-motzkin-paths-and-continued-fractions/).

Comment: Thank you for the link to Qiaochu Yuan's page, and also for adding this to the OEIS. The associated Hankel matrix is totally positive so by a result of (Alan Sokal ?) each $P_n(\sigma)$ should be the moment of a non-negative Borel measure $\mu(t)$ on $[0, \infty)$. By "nice form" I mean, among things, a form which allows access to this measure --- i.e. knowing the support of the measure, and the ability to make basic calculations with the measure (e.g. convolution with other fundamental measures such as Poisson, Bernouli, etc).

Comment: Could you add my stack exchange posting/question as a link to the OEIS listing?

Comment: @JeanneScott Your suggestion of using moments of measures is a very good one. I am still trying to find such a measure, if it exists. No luck yet.